# new Canvas without XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to add an already existing Canvas or make an new Canvas to window without using XAML.

I have a class that works like a button that makes the same type of class if they are pressed. This works but they are now not added in the same canvas that my window uses so i can´t see them. This class and the main window are supposed to use the same Canvas.

// How I imagine how the code should be (its wrong)
this.Add(ClassThatContainsACanvas.CanvasIWantToUse);

//ClassThatContainsACanvas

```
class BundlePS
{
    public static Canvas OUCanvas = new Canvas();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want to write some code in the MainWindow to put the static Canvas into that window?

If so, the call would be (in the MainWindow code):

```
this.Content = BundlePS.OUCanvas;
```

Otherwise, if I've misunderstood the problem please provide a bit more detail on what you want to do!